# Looping each child JSON

Tags: c#

I have a JSON data

```
    "7862707859": {
        "img": "https:\/\/steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net\/economy\/image\/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgposbupIgthwczAaAJB_sm7hIyOqPXmMq3eqWZU7Mxkh9bN9J7yjRrl-UVrMWmiLI6ccgJrMgnT-AK7k7ro08S86cvLyiBgsiYn4XzanxCxn1gSObBepbJw",
        "itemID": "430",
        "type": "Rifle",
        "exterior": "Field-Tested",
        "market_name": "StatTrak\u2122 Galil AR | Shattered (Field-Tested)",
        "price": "1.64",
        "avg": "1.388333",
        "wearvalue": "0.2823500335",
        "inspectLink": "steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview S76561198137155999A7862707859D7506986979364888325"
    }
```

The name `7862707859` is always random so I don't know it. I'm trying to loop through it and get value "Type" from each child. Here is the code

```
foreach (var data in tokenJson["inventory"].Children())
{
    Console.WriteLine(data["market_name"].Value<string>());
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Is it part of an array? A single object like you're showing here?

Comment: My question is how can I loop it through to get the "market_name" value. Code what I added is not working.

Comment: It's part of an array @krillgar

Comment: There is multiple in array `inventory`